# How can I represented multiple if else condition in single line on laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Now I am Trying To Using This Code For Multi Menu Pages Link Building

```
<ul>
  @foreach($main_nav as $mainMenu)
    @if($mainMenu->page_type == "link-page")
        $link = $mainMenu->link;
    @elseif($mainMenu->page_type == "predefine-link")
        $link = route('home').'/'.$mainMenu->link;
    @else
        $link = 'page/'.$mainMenu->slug;
    @endif

    <li>
        <a href="{{ $link }}">
            {{ $mainMenu->title  }}
        </a> 
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

But I Want To Represente Above Code for Single Line on Laravel Blade. I have a idea for isset('')?'':'' for single line but my condition is repeated 3 times so how can I represent multiple if else condition on single line in this format.

```
<ul>   
    @foreach($main_nav as $mainMenu)    
        <li>
            <a href="{{  $mainMenu->page_type == "link-page" ? "$mainMenu->link" : route('home').'/'.$mainMenu->link }}">
                {{ $mainMenu->title  }}
            </a> 
        </li>   
     @endforeach 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think single line is imposible, you can used `@php` in blade, like this example.

```
<ul>
  @foreach($main_nav as $mainMenu)

    @if($mainMenu->page_type == "link-page")
      @php $link = $mainMenu->link; @endphp
    @elseif($mainMenu->page_type == "predefine-link")
      @php $link = route('home').'/'.$mainMenu->link; @endphp
    @else
      @php $link = 'page/'.$mainMenu->slug; @endphp
    @endif

    <li>
      <a href="{{ $link }}">
        {{ $mainMenu->title  }}
      </a>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

i hope this code will solve your problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to accept the `$mainMenu` as a paramenter 
 and run an `if/else`or `switch` statements on `$maninMenu->page_type` if you want to clean your `if/else`. You can create a `helpers.php` file or user `blade`'s `@php` directive.

```
//using `@php`

@php
function assignMainMenuPageType($mainMenu)
{
if($mainMenu->page_type == "link-page")
{
return $mainMenu->link;
}else if($mainMenu->page_type == "predefine-link")
{
return route('home').'/'.$mainMenu->link;
}
return 'page/'.$mainMenu->slug;
}
@endphp

// use the function in your view
<ul>
  @foreach($main_nav as $mainMenu)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ assignMainMenuPageType($mainMenu) }}">
            {{ $mainMenu->title  }}
        </a> 
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested Ternary Operator

```
(IF ? THEN : ELSE(IF ? THEN : ELSE(IF ? THEN : ELSE))
```

In your case it should be:

```
$link = ($mainMenu->page_type == "link-page") ? $mainMenu->link : ( $mainMenu->page_type == "predefine-link" ) ? route('home').'/'.$mainMenu->link : 'page/'.$mainMenu->slug;
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Laravel 8**, all you need is the right structure for conditioning the blade.
Here is the structure for multi-condition in blade:

```
{{                 
    // first condition                                                          
    $value == 0? '':
                                                                            
      ($value <= 25? 'danger':    //False? then new condition
                                                                            
        (value <= 50? 'warning':  //False? then new condition, and so on
                                                                            
          (value <= 75? 'info':
                                                                            
            (value > 75? 'success':'')
          )
        )
      )
}}
```

Of course, spacing is not a deal in **Laravel**, but these spaces just to make you understand well the multi-conditions in **Laravel**